# How can I constrain locators to a limited (but not regular) set of positions?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mouseevent

In Mathematica, locators can be constrained to certain screen regions via the parameters of `LocatorPane`   (See [LocatorPane](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LocatorPane.html) documentation.)

A list of three ordered pairs `{{{minX, minY}, {maxX, maxY}, {dX, dY}}}` is usually the key to determining the behavior of locators.  `{minX, minY}` and `{maxX, maxY}` set the region. `{dX, dY}` sets the jump size: zero for unrestrained, any other positive number for the size of each hop.

In the code below, `{{{-.9, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}}` sets the region and jumps for the locator `pts`. The first two ordered pairs limit the locators to the interval [-9, 1] on the number line. The ordered pair `{0, 0}` imposes no additional constraints on either of the locators.  However, because the y values can only be zero, due to the region defined by the first two items, neither locator is free to leave the x-axis.

I'd like to confine each locator to x-values in `myTicks`. (In the full program, myTicks will change over time depending on decisions made by the user.) Because the ticks are not uniformly spaced along x, the issue cannot be solved by setting a constant value for the x-jump.  And if the value were take into account the current position of the locator, the next left hop might be different size than the right hop.

```
myTicks = {-.9, 0, .1, .2, .45, .79, 1};
pts = {{.25, 0}, {.75, 0}};

LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
  Graphics[{}, 
    Axes -> {True, False}, 
    PlotLabel -> Row[{"locators at: " , Dynamic[pts[[1, 1]]], " and ", 
       Dynamic[pts[[2, 1]]]}], 
    Ticks -> {myTicks, Automatic}],
{{{-.9, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: By the way, I used the `mouseevent` tag because I suspect that there are some subtleties about mouse behavior that may be involved here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to work.

```
myTicks = {-.9, 0, .1, .2, .45, .79, 1};

DynamicModule[{p = {.25, 0}, p2 = {.75, 0}},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[{p, p2}], 
  Graphics[{}, Axes -> {True, False}, 
   PlotLabel -> 
    Row[{"locators at: ", 
      Dynamic[p[[1]] = Nearest[myTicks, p[[1]]][[1]]], " and ", 
      Dynamic[p2[[1]] = Nearest[myTicks, p2[[1]]][[1]]]}], 
   Ticks -> {myTicks, Automatic}], {{{-.9, 0}, {1, 0}}}, ContinuousAction -> False]
]
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  This works very nicely. I like the way you kept the locator's drag-and-drop personality intact: when released, the locator jumps to the nearest tick, as desired.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your implementation actually works more smoothly than the chosen entry. But because both answers relied on `Nearest`, I selected the one submitted first.

Comment: @David As I said to another user, that is of course your prerogative, but I cannot really understand it.  If one selects the first solution that works, and does not change that selection if a better one is presented, there is less incentive to submit improved solutions.  In this case I do not claim that my solution is better, but if it were, why not select it?  Incidentally, I did not see belisarius' use of Nearest (before my own), I just took longer finding a working solution using it.

Comment: @Mr. I agree //two more chars to go

Comment: @Mr. Wizard  @belisarius Am I allowed to change my decision?  Your arguments ring true.  I do think that Mr. Wizard's solution was more polished; and he kept the ticks as ticks. I responded mainly in terms of the order of a functioning solution.

Comment: @David Now wait for belisarius to post an even better solution. :-)

Comment: @Mr. Wizard  Hmmm.   Could happen, I suppose.  But it's kind of hard to imagine improvements in your solution.  In the future, I think I'll hold off at least a couple of days before selecting the best answer. I'm learning as I go.

Answer (score 3):

Let's try this:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {10, 0}};
myTics = Table[{x, 0}, {x, 0, 10, 5}];
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
 ListPlot[myTics, PlotRange -> {{-1, 11}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[.07], Red],
  Epilog -> {PointSize[.05], Blue, h = Point[Dynamic[{Nearest[myTics, pts[[1]]]}]], 
             PointSize[.03], Yellow, j = Point[Dynamic[{Nearest[myTics, pts[[2]]]}]], 
             Black, 
              Text[{"locators at: ", Dynamic[h[[1, 1]]], " and ",Dynamic[j[[1, 1]]]}, 
                    {5, .5}]}],
 Appearance -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: Nearest is very useful! (I hadn't seen it before).

Comment: I chose your entry because you first had the insight of using  `Dynamic[{Nearest[myTics, pts[[1]]]}]`.  I had intended that the ticks be ticks rather than points, but that's a mere issue of cosmetics.

Comment: @David I draw points because I thought the image in the answer is somewhat more clear. You may use whatever you want (or replace the ListPlot[] command completely). I rather prefer Mr.Wizard's solution, just because it's visually more appealing.